# Recreating maps from "The $50 American Road Trip"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maps, cost-path

I would like to recreate for cities in my country the maps represented [here](http://howmuch.net/articles/the-$50-american-road-Trip), using ArcMap. On the same site I found the [calculations](http://howmuch.net/sources/the-$50-road-trip), but I don't really know how to recreate those tables.

After looking on google I found this(https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4d26b2e2671e4939af83a1519b578c98) nice thing, but again, i do not know how to apply the calculations for other places.

I found something similar on gis stack but it's not cost related, it's time related. I cannot post the link because I do not have enough reputation. If you'll search for *Travel time calculator QGIS*, I'm sure you'll find it.

I am not new to ArcGIS, but in this particular I didn't find any relevant info for my problem. Please provide some pointers.

Comment: Can you please include the tables you are trying to recreate within your question itself.  Potential answerers will not always follow links to synthesize your question from multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to use the cost distance analysis tool. You can find more details here:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/understanding-cost-distance-analysis.htm

The pro documentation is similar to the ArcGIS 10 documentation, however appears much clearer to me. You can find the ArcGIS 10 documentation here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cost_Distance/009z00000018000000/

Should also note that this feature is in ArcGIS 9.x and 10.x so you should be able to undertake it regardless.